# How to revert EF Core migration from SQL Server 2016 production machine

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have to revert the last EF Core migration from a productive instance from a SQL Server 2016 with no Visual Studio installed. How to do this?

Note: I already tried to install .NET SDK on the server but nevertheless it does not know the command `dotnet ef`. Executing the command results in 
`No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate the SQL script to revert a migration using the `Script-Migration` or `dotnet ef migrations script` command.

```
dotnet ef migrations script TheAppliedMigration TheMigrationBeforeIt -o revert.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Generates a SQL script from the specified from migration to the specified to migration using the 'Script-Migration' from visual studio.

```
Script-Migration MigrationFromNew MigrationToOld
```

Run the Sql script to revert the changes

ref : [EF core Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs)

Any way is in [bricelam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48691640/193061) using the dotnet ef commands